JetBrains DataGrip Single-Click Open Database Sub-Folders?
I'm using JetBrains DataGrip for database management, and I find it tedious to open database subfolders with double click. Is there a way to configure DataGrip to open a database subfolders with a single click?
This feature is already available in other JetBrains IDEs, where you can open directories and files with a single click. Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this?

Buy mouse like Razer Deathadder V2 Pro and create macro to double click

This option applies to files for editing in our IDEs only, not for objects within the database explorer. If you are looking for a specific object, we have Autoscroll from Editor option, which focuses on the object of your interest immediately as soon as you focus on it in the editor. If this doesn't cover your use case, I'd encourage you to create a feature on our tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE
